# Inconsistent datatypes in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-00932

i have the following function:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION "MXUPGKEYVAL"(tbname varchar2,colname varchar2) return number is
val number;

BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'select sum(length('||colname||')) from '||tbname into val;

return val;
END;
```

and the following update:

```
update ANINTEGDATA set val1=to_char(nvl(MXUPGKEYVAL(MX5T,MX5C),0)) where type=1;
```

when i execute the update i get:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG
ORA-06512: at "MAXIMO.MXUPGKEYVAL", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

any idea why that happens?

Regards,
Radu.

Later edit:

table ANINTEGDATA is:

```
create table ANINTEGDATA
(
  MX5T VARCHAR2(50),
  MX5C VARCHAR2(50),
  MX6T VARCHAR2(50),
  MX6C VARCHAR2(50),
  TYPE NUMBER,
  VAL1 VARCHAR2(200),
  VAL2 VARCHAR2(200)
);
```

Comment: Hi Radu, we can't give you a correct answer if you don't give us some sample data and the column datatypes of this table: `ANINTEGDATA(val1,type,MX5T,MX5C)`.

Comment: Hi Vincent. Thank you for your response. I added the datatypes of the ANINTEGDATA table. the table contains values for MX5T, MX5C and type fields now. MX5T and MX5C fields contain table names and column names of various tables on the same schema.

Comment: The first argument to MXUPGKEYVAL is apparently supposed to be a table name, and in the example this argument is given as 'MX5T' (I believe this should be enclosed in quotes).  Is there an MX5T table?  This is also a column name on ANINTEGDATA.  If there is an MX5T table could you please post the definition of this table?  If not, please check that the function definition shown above is up-to-date.  I've created the ANINTEGDATA table and MXUPGKEYVAL function as shown above but got errors different from the ones you received.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function works.

```
SQL> select mxupgkeyval('EMP', 'SAL') from dual
  2  /

MXUPGKEYVAL('EMP','SAL')
------------------------
                      78

SQL>
```

Furthermore it works in your update statement.

```
SQL> update ANINTEGDATA set val1=to_char(nvl(MXUPGKEYVAL(MX5T,MX5C),0)) where type=1;

1 row updated.

SQL>
```

Where it doesn't work is when the column in question has the LONG datatype.  The error message isn't as clear as it could be but is clear enough.

```
SQL> alter table t34 add long_col long;

Table altered.

SQL> select mxupgkeyval('T34', 'LONG_COL') from dual
  2  /
select mxupgkeyval('T34', 'LONG_COL') from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got LONG
ORA-06512: at "APC.MXUPGKEYVAL", line 6


SQL>
```

This is just another reason why LONG is Teh Suck! and should have been done away with a long time ago.  As you're doing a data migration exercise now would be a good time to consider moving to the oh-so flexible CLOB data type.

Either way you need a convention to indicate that the target column contains a shedload of data.

If you really need to know the precise extent of the LONG data volumes I suggest you unload the LONGs to CLOB columns and sum those instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response. On the new environment we already have clob datatype. Regards, Radu.

Comment: @RaduDragomir - That's good.  We can use CLOBs pretty much like any other column.  They are a lot less hassle than LONGs.